# sanity checks in python properties function partially

Tags: python, class, properties

I'm new to python and I would like some help. I created some classes with properties in order to keep me from passing meaningless arguments.

So for example I have this class

```
class match(object):
     __teams=(None,None)

     def setTeams(self,tms):
          if type(tms) != type(list()) and type(tms) != type(tuple()):
               raise Exception("Teams must be a list of length 2")
          if len(tms) != 2:
               raise Exception("Teams must be a list of length 2")
          if (type(tms[0])==type(str()) or (type(tms[0])==type(unicode()))) \
          and (type(tms[1])==type(str()) or type(tms[1])==type(unicode())):
               self.__teams=tms
          else:
               raise Exception("Both teams must be strings")
          return

      teams=property(getTeams,setTeams)
```

If I write

```
match1=match()
match1.teams=(2,4)
```

I get an exception as I should, but

```
match1.teams[0]=5
```

does not raise an exception and passes the number 5. Please keep in mind that this is not all of the class, I just wrote down only what is relative to my question, so assume that the code behaves as I describe.

I guess this is because everything is passed by reference in python but I have to be careful not to assign meaningless data to my objects which defeats the purpose of having properties in the first place.

So, is there a way to fix that apart from not using lists or do I have to learn to live with it?

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer (click on the check-mark by the one you want).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the advantages of `property`s is being able to do data validation -- sometimes it is really important to make sure you get something very specific.

In your case you need to do one of two things:

- store your `teams` data in a structure that can't be modified, such as a `tuple` or `namedtuple`; then when the data is retrieved it cannot be changed

or

- have your `get` method return a copy of the data, so any modification do not mess up your original

The first solution (immutable types) looks like this:

```
class match(object):
    __teams=(None,None)

    def setTeams(self,tms):
        "any sequence type will do, as long as length is two"
        if len(tms) != 2:
            raise TypeError(
                "Teams must be a sequence of length 2"
                )
        if not isinstance(tms[0], (str, unicode)):
            raise TypeError(
                "Team names must be str or unicode, not %r" % type(tms[0])
                )
        if not isinstance(tms[1], (str, unicode)):
            raise TypeError(
                "Team names must be str or unicode, not %r" % type(tms[0])
                )
        self.__teams = tuple(tms)

    def getTeams(self):
        return self.__teams

    teams=property(getTeams,setTeams)
```

And when you try to assign after getting the value, this happens:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 22, in <module>
    match1.teams[0]=5
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

The second solution (returning a copy instead of the original) looks like this:

```
class match(object):
    __teams=(None,None)

    def setTeams(self,tms):
        "any sequence type will do, as long as length is two"
        if len(tms) != 2:
            raise TypeError(
                "Teams must be a sequence of length 2"
                )
        if not isinstance(tms[0], (str, unicode)):
            raise TypeError(
                "Team names must be str or unicode, not %r" % type(tms[0])
                 )
        if not isinstance(tms[1], (str, unicode)):
            raise TypeError(
                "Team names must be str or unicode, not %r" % type(tms[0])
                )
        self.__teams = list(tms)

    def getTeams(self):
        return list(self.__teams)

    teams=property(getTeams,setTeams)

# and the code in action...
match1=match()
match1.teams=('us',u'them')

match1.teams[0]=5
print match1.teams
```

which has the following results:

```
['us', u'them']
```

As you can see, the changes did not make it back into the `match` object.

Comment: Actually returning a copy of the data is an excellent idea. do you know what is the excess processing load of this?

Comment: @user977506: Making a shallow copy is minor, but even if it wasn't you shouldn't worry about it until profiling has shown that to be a bottleneck.

Answer (score 5):

This error isn't because you are failing some typecheck.

Unless you have misrepresented your code (it's obviously edited, as what you posted won't run correctly), this is happening because `match1.teams[0]` calls your `getTeams` function, not your `setTeams` function.  To see this for yourself, try this exercise:

```
class match(object):
    __teams=(None,None)
    def setTeams(self,tms):
        print "in set"
        self.__teams = tms
    def getTeams(self):
        print "in get"
        return self.__teams
    teams=property(getTeams,setTeams)
```

When I try this, I get the following:

```
>>> match1 = match()
>>> match1.teams[0]=5
in get
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
>>> match1.teams = ["team1","team2"]
in set
>>> match1.teams[0]=5
in get
```

Comment: Nate you are right, the get method is used. So Petr is right, I am out of luck. Thank you both.

Answer (score 4):

Python and type checks don't go together. Learn to live with it. It's the job of whoever uses the code to pass the proper types. Document what your code expects, but don't check it explicitly.

There are other collections than lists and tuples. Why would you forbid, say, [namedtuple](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)? Python is a dynamic language, don't fight it by writing type checks.

Look up [EAFP](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-eafp) in the Python glossary. Don't try to anticipate errors; deal with them as they happen.

---

A reasonable thing you might do instead of type checking is converting to a list:

```
self.__teams = list(tms)
```

List-incompatible types will cause an exception to be raised on this line, and from now on you can be sure you're dealing with a list.
(It won't prevent someone from assigning non-strings to the list, of course.)

---

Oh, and if you ever (with good reason!) need a type check, use the [isinstance](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#isinstance) function instead of comparing the `type()`. That will also catch subclasses of whatever your required type is. And more, try to use the most general base type you can. The proper way to test for a string (Unicode or otherwise) is:

```
if isinstance(my_object, basestring):
    ....
```

And the proper way to check for a list-like collection – not just a narrow-minded “list or tuple” – is:

```
import collections
if isinstance(my_object, collections.Sequence):
    ...
```

But that was just an aside, not the proper solution to your problem. Don't do type checking without good reason.

Comment: Thanks Petr, you are probably right, there is no point into doing that.

Comment: Using collections.Sequence will fail if the type is not registered, and since ABC's are optional, there are sure to be many that are not.

Comment: @EthanFurman: Well, yes. Checking ABCs is better than `isinstance(..., (list, tuple))` because you can at least use ABCs as a crutch to please the code that does the checks. No checks are, of course better still.

Comment: (for the record, not *all* ABCs are optional – `isinstance(..., Sized)` is true for anything with a `__len__`)

Comment: Incorrect -- my dbf class has a `__len__` method, and instances of it fail `isinstance(..., Sized)`.

Comment: I disagree -- checking ABC's is imposing additional requirements; it also may allow items it should not:  range() objects pass that test, but would blow up later in the code.

Comment: @EthanFurman Hmm. *anything* might have been too general. But a simple class with just a `__len__` is Sized; I wonder what your dbf class does to disable that. And yes, checking ABCs will give false negatives, but at least it'll not prevent legitimate uses.

Comment: I hate when I'm wrong -- I must have typo'd something earlier, because it is indeed working now.  Thanks for teaching me something!